# Secure File Transfer Using Cron

Tags: cron, sftp

I have a cron job which backs up my database and ftp's it to my home machine.  However, as I understand it ftp is not a secure way to transfer files.

I'v read quite a few things on this subject but non of them will work for me because:

- I don't have shell access to my remote hosting account
- I can connect to my remote host via sftp, but going the other way sftp will not allow me to use the [-i identity file] option on my remote hosting account to authenticate with my home machine.
- I don't have an SSL certificate and would rather not have to buy one.

What is the best way for me to transfer files from my remote server to my home machine?  The method needs to be secure and scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have shell access how would you update the cron? I always use `crontab -e` but without shell you probably can't.

Anyway, if you can modify the cron you could have the file you want transferred to a non-web accessible directory and then SFTP in from your home machine once a day - after the backup on the server should be complete - and have the home machine initiate the download.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to have to do anything manually.  I'd rather schedule my computer to turn off/on at the right time to receive the file and have everything scripted.  I add cron jobs through cpanel.